# How do I deploy this Traefik example to Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I am following the Getting Started guide for Traefik from [here](https://docs.traefik.io/) and am trying to launch the service into Kubernetes (Minikube) instead of Docker:

```
Edit your docker-compose.yml file and add the following at the end of your file.
# ...
  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"**
```

I am guessing I run it as:

```
kubectl run whoami-service --image=emilevauge/whoami --labels='traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost'
```

however that generates an error of:

```
The Deployment "whoami-service" is invalid:
* metadata.labels: Invalid value: "'traefik.frontend.rule": name part must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and....
```

So what am I missing here? How do I deploy the above to my Minikube Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is along the lines of what you're looking for, but Traefik has a [small tutorial](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/) for getting an Ingress controller set up on Kubernetes, with a [great document](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/kubernetes/) on configuration, as well.

If you'd just like to get that particular image working, you may be able to pass the label as an argument to the pod, possibly with `kubectl run`. From the output of `kubectl run help`:

```
# Start the nginx container using the default command, but use custom arguments (arg1 .. argN) for that command.
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx -- <arg1> <arg2> ... <argN>
```

Or possibly manually in a manifest:

```
...
containers:
  - name: whoami
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    args: ["traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:whoami.docker.localhost"]
```

Having never worked with the image in the example before, I don't know if either the above examples will actually work.

Hope that helps a little!